# Failed to initialize OneDS

Tags: azure-functions, microsoft-information-protection

I have a Azure Function which uses MIP SDK and I am getting the following error when calling `MIP.CreateMipContext(...)`:

```
Failed to initialize OneDS (mipns::OneDSHelper::OneDSHelper:src\core\api_impl\diagnostic\oneds\oneds_helper.cpp:173
```

Surprisingly, the error occurs only when running on Azure. When running locally, everything is fine.

I am using **MIP SDK v1.8.86** and **.NET Core 3.1**.

Any ideas what that OneDS is or what is causing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OneDS is the library used for diagnostic data and to send audit events for AIP Analytics. I reviewed the source for that error, and the failing function does accept the logpath, the base of which will be the path you set when creating the MipContext. Can you check to make sure you're able to write to that location?

Comment: I have set IsLocalCachingEnabled = false in the DiagnosticConfiguration when calling MIP.CreateMipContext(). I have also provided ILoggerDelegate. Is it still necessary to provide a writable path?

Comment: Yes, that should remove the local cache, but I'll need to test or validate with engineering.

Comment: I can confirm the error occurs even when IsLocalCachingEnabled is set to false and ILoggerDelegate is provided. More interestingly, when I changed the log level from Error to Trace then the error was gone. Anyway,  providing a writable path fixed the issue too.